# Infinite scroll stopped working after switching to production mode

Tags: magento2

I had Strategery infinite scroll extension installed and running correctly on my Magento 2.2.2 store,while it was in development mode.

Today when I switched to production mode, it stopped working on frontend, though it is still enabled and all its configurations are correct.

I have tried to disable JavaScript minfy and combining, yet it is still not functioning well.

**P.S :**
 I have one new error in console that says: "SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break"

**Update:**
I solved it by changing default spinner to a custom one, it seems to have been the inclusion of it, though I am still unsure why it appeared only in production mode.

Comment: Switched to production mode. And that was it?  Nothing else done?  What about cache? What errors do you see in the browser console?

Comment: only switching to production mode, if I switch back to development mode it works just fine.
I have one new error in console:
SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break

Comment: you gave me a hint that lead to solving the problem, thank you @df2k2

Comment: Based on the error it seems that a data feed contains newline characters, which leads to an exception. Could you add a log output from system.log or debug.log (depends on which gets filled with the error) to the question?

Comment: the problem have been solved, I have updated my question explaining how I did it, thank you for commenting @ Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had posted questions in the comments section:

> Switched to production mode. And that was it? Nothing else done? What about cache? What errors do you see in the browser console?

The author revealed that there was an error in the console:

> I have one new error in console that says: "SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break"

In my opinion, tracking the issue and resolving it may have been beneficial for the community, but the most important part is that the issue has been resolved.  What we can take away from this post is to check for debug/error messages in the output console of the browser.

The solution work-around here was to swap out a broken JavaScript component to working JavaScript component.